# How to remove subdomains from domains using javascript

Tags: javascript, regex, replace, dns, url-parsing

I am starting with domains that look like this:

```
www.exemple.com
main.testsite.com
www.ex-emple.com.ar
main.test-site.co.uk
en.tour.mysite.nl
www.ip.com
www.one.lv
```

and I need to remove the subdomains to get values that look like this:

```
exemple.com
testsite.com
ex-emple.com.ar
test-site.co.uk
mysite.nl
ip.com
one.lv
```

other top level domains:

```
.ac
.ad
.ae
.af
.ag
.ai
.al
.am
.ao
.aq
.ar
.as
.asia
.at
.au
.aw
.ax
.az
.ba
.bb
.bd
.be
.bf
.bg
.bh
.bi
.bj
.bm
.bn
.bo
.br
.bs
.bt
.bw
.by
.bz
.ca
.cc
.cd
.cf
.cg
.ch
.ci
.ck
.cl
.cm
.cn
.co
.co.ao
.co.ba
.co.bw
.co.cc
.co.ck
.co.cr
.co.fk
.co.id
.co.il
.co.im
.co.in
.co.jp
.co.ke
.co.kr
.co.ls
.co.ma
.co.mz
.co.nl
.co.nz
.co.th
.co.tz
.co.ug
.co.uk
.co.uz
.co.ve
.co.vi
.co.za
.co.zm
.co.zw
.com
.com.af
.com.ag
.com.ai
.com.al
.com.ar
.com.au
.com.aw
.com.az
.com.bb
.com.bd
.com.bh
.com.bi
.com.bm
.com.bn
.com.bo
.com.br
.com.bs
.com.bt
.com.by
.com.bz
.com.cm
.com.cn
.com.co
.com.cu
.com.cv
.com.cy
.com.do
.com.dz
.com.ec
.com.ee
.com.eg
.com.es
.com.et
.com.fj
.com.ge
.com.gh
.com.gi
.com.gl
.com.gn
.com.gp
.com.gr
.com.gt
.com.gu
.com.hk
.com.hn
.com.hr
.com.ht
.com.jm
.com.jo
.com.kg
.com.kh
.com.ki
.com.kw
.com.ky
.com.kz
.com.lb
.com.lc
.com.lk
.com.lr
.com.lv
.com.ly
.com.mg
.com.mk
.com.mm
.com.mo
.com.mt
.com.mu
.com.mv
.com.mw
.com.mx
.com.my
.com.na
.com.nf
.com.ng
.com.ni
.com.np
.com.nr
.com.om
.com.pa
.com.pe
.com.pg
.com.ph
.com.pk
.com.pl
.com.pr
.com.ps
.com.pt
.com.py
.com.qa
.com.ro
.com.sa
.com.sb
.com.sc
.com.sg
.com.sl
.com.sn
.com.sv
.com.sy
.com.tj
.com.tn
.com.tr
.com.tt
.com.tw
.com.ua
.com.uy
.com.uz
.com.vc
.com.ve
.com.vi
.com.vn
.com.ye
.cr
.cv
.cx
.cy
.cz
.de
.dj
.dk
.dm
.do
.dz
.ec
.edu
.ee
.eg
.es
.eu
.fi
.fj
.fk
.fm
.fo
.fr
.ga
.gd
.ge
.gf
.gg
.gh
.gi
.gl
.gm
.gn
.gov
.gp
.gq
.gr
.gs
.gt
.gu
.gy
.hk
.hm
.hn
.hr
.ht
.hu
.id
.ie
.il
.im
.in
.io
.iq
.is
.it
.je
.jm
.jo
.jp
.ke
.kg
.kh
.ki
.km
.kn
.kr
.kw
.ky
.kz
.la
.lb
.lc
.li
.lk
.lr
.ls
.lt
.lu
.lv
.ly
.ma
.mc
.md
.me
.mg
.mil
.mk
.ml
.mm
.mn
.mo
.mobi
.mp
.mq
.mr
.ms
.mt
.mu
.mv
.mw
.mx
.my
.na
.name
.nc
.ne
.ne.jp
.net
.net.ck
.net.cm
.net.in
.nf
.ng
.ni
.nl
.no
.np
.nr
.nu
.nz
.og.ao
.om
.or.th
.org
.org.ck
.org.cn
.org.ls
.pa
.pe
.pf
.pg
.ph
.pk
.pl
.pm
.pn
.pr
.pro
.ps
.pt
.py
.qa
.re
.ro
.rs
.ru
.rw
.sa
.sb
.sc
.se
.sg
.sh
.si
.sk
.sl
.sm
.sn
.so
.sr
.st
.su
.sv
.sy
.tc
.td
.tf
.tg
.th
.tj
.tk
.tl
.tm
.tn
.to
.tr
.tt
.tv
.tw
.tz
.ua
.ug
.uk
.us
.uy
.uz
.vc
.ve
.vg
.vi
.vn
.vu
.wf
.ws
.xxx
.ye
.yt
.za
.zm
.zw
```

Comment: With the `.replace` method: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace. If you have problems with your code, please post it.

Comment: In order to do this you'll have to know the valid TLDs and as such I have added them back into the question. It may help inform those posting their answers.

Comment: Have a look at these two: [Regex for extracting second level domain from FQDN?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1774541/regex-for-extracting-second-level-domain-from-fqdn) and [Need a regular expression to capture second level domain (SLD)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4452916/need-a-regular-expression-to-capture-second-level-domain-sld), especially the second one.

Comment: [psl](https://www.npmjs.com/package/psl) library on npm does what you are asking. Code: `const domain = psl.get(host);`. It uses Mozilla's [Public suffix list](https://publicsuffix.org/list/) which is considered the official resource for this information.

Comment: @chickens Correct. And one can include it directly to a page like: `<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/psl/1.9.0/psl.min.js">`

Comment: @MarinosAn, please don't make edits that substantially change the gist of the question. You are assuming a lot here.

Answer (score 11):

```
var result = string.replace(/^[^.]+\./g, "");
```

Comment: Any reason for the downvote? Is it the case that OP wanted to retain exactly the second-level domains, considering things like `co.uk` as a TLD?

Comment: I gave you a +1, but I guess @usr13's "en.tour.mysite.nl" => "mysite.nl" replacement doesn't work with your answer, so maybe they are looking for "domain" ".com" "optional .uk" and not always removing the _first_ piece?

Comment: @RobI: thanks for the hint, it's actually hard to deduce the common rule for the replacement.

Comment: regex is a bit like the rubix cube. Will be very interesting to see if a single regex can handle all the domains given without reference to an allowed extensions array

Comment: This doesn't seem like it would work for multiple subdomains such as "en.tour.mysite.nl"

Comment: @gimp3695 This works with multiple subdomains: var result = string.split(".").slice(-2).join(".")
It doesn't work with domains such as "co.uk".

Answer (score 1):

[psl](https://www.npmjs.com/package/psl) library on npm does what you are asking.

```
const domain = psl.get(host);
```

It uses Mozilla's [Public suffix list](https://publicsuffix.org/list/) which is considered the official resource for this information.